# SQL Server "Optional" FreeText Search

Tags: sql-server, freetext

I'm writing a search query in SQL Server 2005 for a discussion board.  The proc takes several parameters, but most are "optional".  There's one search field for Message Body, which I have a full text index on.  Here's the problem..

If I pass in a value to search against with FreeText, the search works fine (thank you Microsoft).  However, the message body field is optional, meaning that in my query, I want to handle a "search all".  How can I default my query to just use any\all records regardless of the data held in my message body field?

I know this doesn't work, but if no value is returned for the message body parameter, Im looking for something like:

```
where (FREETEXT(msg.messagebody, '*'))
```

Comment: I need the solution. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

> select * from Products_CatalogProducts where (@keywords='*' or freetext(msg.messagebody,@keywords))

Assuming you passed in @keywords with a * if it's blank

Comment: Thanks STeve, I apologize if I mislead what I was looking for.  The problem is that the "*" doesnt work.  So what Im really looking for is a value I can pass that will just search "all", know what I mean?  Thanks for your time...

Comment: Give it a go, what this will do is return all results if the @keywords='*' or if it's not then it will do the free text search

Comment: Can you please tell the solution for this?

Comment: sorry for last comment that was for another question.<br>
yes i tried this and this wildcard is not supported in freetexttable, while this is freetext which is different. i was actually looking for such thing in my case where i am using freetexttable